# Are the items featured in Yuru Yuri San Hai! cross review based on real items?

Tags: yuru-yuri

At the end of every episode of Yuru Yuri San Hai! (third season of Yuru Yuri), there is a cross-review section (right before the preview of next episode) which features an item used in the main section of the episode. For example, the shirt that Toshinou Kyouko bought that says I am AHO (AHO is Japanese, means stupid).

[image: Toshinou Kyouko I am AHO]

I can find that shirt being sold in the Internet, though I'm not sure which one comes first, the shirt or the anime. This makes me curious, are the items featured in the cross-review section are actually based on real world items, or this t-shirt is just a coincidence? By coincidence, I mean it just happen to be famous and thus was created or the shirt got featured because when the series creator browse the Internet for idea he/she thought that it is funny.

Comment: When i have seen these shirts advertised it's normally Kyoko or Sakurako wearing it

Comment: By [looking on google](http://i.imgur.com/cp6tnqd.png), we can see that the product sellers claim those shirts to be extracted from the anime. We can say almost without a doubt that the shirt was at first a YuruYuri joke, and then became a product

Answer (score 3):

Most of the cross review items shown in Yuru Yuri are not real. The only things I am able to find is the "I am aho" T-shirt, Akari body pillow, and the candy in episode 9 (it's made by the same company, but it's called 森永ミルクキャラメル、MORINAGA MILK CARAMEL). The books in the cross review might be real, but unfortunately I can not find them, and the other ones like the dog house and lie tester are not real. The volleyball is obviously real, but the volleyball branded Moiken is not. I might be a bit off but hope this helps.